# Folding an integer array in half

Tags: java

I am working on a method that will take an integer array and fold it in half x number of times. This method would take an integer array like this {1,2,3,4,5} and output an the array {6,6,3} if it is folded once. Or it could take the input {5,6,7,8} and output {13,13} also folded once.

If the input is folded twice then {5,6,7,8} would turn into {26}.

```
import java.util.Arrays;
public class Kata
{
  public static int[] foldArray(int[] array, int runs)
  { 
    int[] tempArray = array;

    for(int j=0; j<runs; j++){
      for(int i=0; i<tempArray.length; i++){
        tempArray[i] += tempArray[tempArray.length - i];
      }
    }

    int[] outputArray = Arrays.copyOfRange(tempArray, (tempArray.length/2));
    return outputArray;
  } 
}
```

Comment: For the first example, shouldn't it be {6, 3, 6}?

Comment: You should explain what the relationship between `{1,2,3,4,5}` and `{6,6,3}` is. Also, you didn't ask a question. If your code doesn't work, you need to explain that.

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: No, fold on 3 so it stays the same. @CoffeehouseCoder

Comment: what is runs here?

Answer (score 2):

The problem with your implementation is the way in which you use `tempArray`:

```
int[] tempArray = array;
```

This "aliases" `tempArray` to the original `array`, so any modifications to `tempArray` also happen to the original array. This means that `tempArray`'s `length` is not going to change from run to run, so any fold after the first one would be invalid.

You need to make `tempArray` a copy of the initial ⌈n/2⌉ elements on each iteration of the outer loop. To round half-length up, use this expression:

```
int halfLength = (tempArray.length+1)/2;
int[] tempArray = Arrays.copyOfRange(tempArray, halfLength);
```

This will deal with arrays of odd length.

At the end of each outer loop iteration replace `array` with `tempArray`.

Answer (score 2):

You can also solve your problem recursively:

```
public static int[] foldArray(int[] array, int runs) {

    if (runs == 0) {
        return array;
    }

    int[] tmp;
    if (array.length % 2 == 0) {
        tmp = new int[array.length / 2];
        for (int i = 0; i < array.length / 2; i++) {
            tmp[i] = array[i];
        }
    } else {
        tmp = new int[array.length / 2 + 1];
        for (int i = 0; i < array.length / 2 + 1; i++) {
            tmp[i] = array[i];
        }
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < array.length / 2; i++) {
        tmp[i] += array[array.length - i - 1];
    }
    return foldArray(tmp, runs - 1);

}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(foldArray(new int[]{1, 2, 3, 4, 5}, 1)));
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(foldArray(new int[]{5, 6, 7, 8}, 1)));
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(foldArray(new int[]{5, 6, 7, 8}, 2)));
}
```

Note that you need to be careful with the length of the input arrays - whether it's odd or even.

Answer (score -1):

A solution in `JavaScript`:

```
function foldArray(array, folds) {
    while (folds > 0) {
        var half = Math.floor(array.length / 2);
        for (var i = 0; i < half; i++) {
            array[i] += array.pop();
        }
        folds--;
    }
    return array;
}
```

Example:

```
const arr = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];

fold(arr, 2);  --> [9,6]
```